# Coinbase oauth2 login with flutter on android. Custom android uri schemes are blocked by chrome

Tags: android, flutter

I want to login using coinbase oauth2 in my flutter app android and ios .I use flutter_web_auth package , the authentication is stuck on processing for android(all the android native code and coinbase API setup is correct) and works well for ios .Below is the link for more details .

https://github.com/LinusU/flutter_web_auth/issues/83

I tried below link in android 10, chrome  browser it is stuck on processing page ,

https://www.coinbase.com/oauth/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=your_client_is&redirect_uri=your_redirect_uri ,but the same link works well in laptop

when i inspect the chrome browser of android phone  it gives below error  (works well on firefox mobile browser  though)

jquery-cb0decd18b4b0abbece3cfc180d9adc8e11dfa693cf34c2ff1ffcda86e725301.js:2 Mixed Content: The page at 'https://www.coinbase.com/oauth/authorize' was loaded over a secure connection, but contains a form that targets an insecure endpoint 'my.myapp.app://myapp-oauth'. This endpoint should be made available over a secure connection.

jquery-cb0decd18b4b0abbece3cfc180d9adc8e11dfa693cf34c2ff1ffcda86e725301.js:2 Mixed Content: The page at 'https://www.coinbase.com/oauth/authorize' was loaded over a secure connection, but contains a form that targets an insecure endpoint 'my.myapp.app://myapp-oauth/'. This endpoint should be made available over a secure connection.
trigger @ jquery-cb0decd18b4b0abbece3cfc180d9adc8e11dfa693cf34c2ff1ffcda86e725301.js:2
authorize:1
Navigation is blocked: my.myapp.app://myapp-oauth?code=1cbfd2f26d220a5fda629f6dc75b0ea6c7281c946863452be4415ca04dbea5c6&state=alcmwppxlk9p5k3wbbxyv5t4a